# Cannot paste URLS using vim

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, vim

I have been trying to set up an RRS feed using newsboat.
As directed by

#Error: no URLs configured. Please fill the file /home/titus/snap/newsboat/6008/.newsboat/urls with RSS feed URLs or import an OPML file.

I have tried pasting in RRS URLS by opening the /urls file with vim but get this page.
[my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH18R.png)

How do I paste the URL here, if this is even the correct place or method of doing so?
Worth noting that the URLS file did not exist in / .newsboat until i created it, despite my initial terminal feedback suggesting this is the correct place to paste the RRS URLS.

I'm fairly new to ubuntu hence the want of an RRS feed.

Comment: RRS?  do you mean RSS feeds?  I can copy/paste URLs fine using `vim` though I have not used the reader you mention (which is a RSS reader, not RRS)

Comment: Thank you, I do mean RRS feeds, yes. I'll try using a different RRS reader and hopefully this problem will not occur.